# How Do I Sort Bar Chart by Month Names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code but I want it to be sort by Month instead of totals.
The date format is YYYY-MM-DD

```
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['total'].sum().sort_values().plot.bar(figsize=(20,10))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The month names are strings, and Python doesn't know how to relate those with the actual order. You can try `reindex`:

```
# you need to type this in
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
          'May', 'June', 'July', 'August',
          'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

(df.groupby(df['date'].dt.strftime('%B'))
   ['total'].sum()
   .reindex(months)
   .plot.bar(figsize=(20,10))
)
```

Or, less error prone is to groupby on the numeric months along with the names, then discard the numbers:

```
(df.groupby([df['date'].dt.month,df['date'].dt.strftime('%B')])
   ['total'].sum()
   .reset_index(level=0)
   .plot.bar(figsize=(20,10))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the `sort_values()` function how you'd like it to do so. Try replacing that part of the expression with `sort_values(by='date')`

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new column as Month and sort by it:

```
df['Month'] = df['date'].dt.month    
df.groupby('Month').sum().sort_values(by = 'Month')['total'].plot.bar(figsize=(20,10))
```

results in:
[image]

If you want order to be alphabetical, make month column accordingly:

```
df['Month'] = df['date'].dt.month_name()
df.groupby('Month').sum().sort_values(by = 'Month')['total'].plot.bar(figsize=(20,10))
```

results in:

[image]